# iPad javascript print() method does not work in fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, airprint

I'm building a web application which has support for iPad (Safari in fullscreen mode (-> Add to Home Screen)).

When I call the print() Method in Javascript in fullscreen mode the AirPrint dialog appears but nothing happens when I select "Print".

When you do the same in "normal" Safari without fullscreen mode the page will be printed.

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of limitations of these sandboxed web apps and I assume printing is one of them.